# Limit of $\lim_{x\to 1} (\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln x})$ without Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried to solve this limit 
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln x}\right)$$
and, without thinking, I thought the result was 1. But, using wolfram to verify, I noticed that the limit is $1/2$.

How can I solve it without Hopital/series/integration, just with known limits (link in comments) /squeeze/basic therem?

I don't have a clue about what I can do, because known limits can't be used ($\ln x = x-1$) without considering the "error" that we don't exactly know!

Comment: Can you assume that the limit exists, and need only find its value, or do you also need to prove the existence?

Comment: I can't assume that it exists!

Comment: Then, what can you use? Is $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{e^t-1-t}{t^2}$ known?

Comment: No, we can't use it!

Comment: What **can** you use?

Comment: Asymptotic, known limits, everything before derivation and  I can't use sostitution!

Comment: How on earth should we know what the set of "known limits" is for you?

Comment: http://www.docsity.com/documents/pages/2012/10/30/d9d7e75cb3cc431c6b7fb325630d2be1.png
First column: all; Second Column: 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: First of all, your instructor is terrible. Artificially limiting which methods can be used to solve a problem is not how math is done. Secondly, you should have clearly specified what you needed in your original question. This way other users don't waste time writing answers you don't want.

Comment: My error, and I am sorry of that. We are at university from a lot of different schools, our preparation is different and we can't use what we already know because others couldn't know it, and there is always a way for these exercise. I am sorry for the time wasted, I'll assign best answer to the ones that used sostitution because I didn't stated that I don't know it. Thanks for the help and sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x=e^{y}$, then $y\to 0$ implies $x\to1$. So
$$
\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac1{\ln(x)}=\frac1{1-e^{y}}-\frac1y
$$
Using the power series of the exponential, $e^{-y}=1-y+\frac12y^2+O(y^3)$, one can transform to
$$
=\frac1{y\bigl(1-\frac12y+O(y^2)\bigr)}-\frac1y=\frac{(1+\frac12y+O(y^2))-1}y=\frac12+O(y)
$$

Comment: We still don't have done sostitution, so it might be another way to solve it! But this is the method that can fit it better, always if there isn't a way without sostitution!

Comment: Then you need to transform the logarithm using its differential or inequalities based on its Taylor series, i.e., $\ln(1+y)=y-y^2/2+O(y^3)$. Please read up on whack-a-mole, your teacher or whoever made the syllabus seems to orient their teaching style on that game.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$$

and that for $1 < t < x$ $$2-t < \frac{1}{t} < \frac{\frac{1}{x}-1}{x-1}(t-1) +1.$$

Integration in $t$ from $1$ to $x$ results in $$0 < \frac{(3-x)(x-1)}{2} < \ln(x) < \frac{(1+\frac{1}{x})(x-1)}{2}$$ for all $x\in(1,3)$.  Therefore on the same interval

$$ \frac{2-x}{3-x}<\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln(x)}< \frac{x}{x+1} $$

and $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

For $x\in(0,1)$ all inequalities change direction and therefore also

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Hence we will get
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: We are not allowed to use derivative nor integration, sorry for not writing this!

Comment: Then how do you define $\ln(x)$?

Comment: I know that $\ln x$ is asymptotic to $x-1$ for x -> 1, but I can't use that! So I don't know

Comment: @L.Repetti: No, I mean in general, if you are working with the logarithm then you should know some definition from which its properties follow.

Comment: Probably, not having defined it, I don't know what do you mean by definition!

Comment: Some use $\ln(x):=\lim n(\sqrt[n]x-1)$, others $\ln(x):=\int_1^x\frac{dt}t$, others as the inverse function of the exponential which in turn can be defined by the series $\exp(x)=\sum\frac{x^n}{n!}$, the exponential function $e^x$ with base $e=\exp(1)$, the limit of the sequence $\exp(x)=\lim (1+\frac xn)^n$ or as solution of the differential equation $y'=y$. Some of that should be known to you.